# Get the search filter used in list view to context Odoo

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I have  a list view like any other:
[image]

now when i click on "imprimer" button i'll have a wizard pop up ,i want to pass the search value as a context ,for example here : partenaire have "Woo" in it
and i have no idea how to access to it ,i don't mind if it's with JS

Comment: You can access the filtered records ids in the context (`active_ids`)

Comment: Can you give me an example !!

Comment: Try to get the active ids in the function executed when you click on "imprimer" button

Comment: i found a quick solution with js ,i'm gonna share it if anyone needs it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with JS :
in the button function :

```
action_def: function (e) {
        
           var self = this;
           var active_id = this.model.get(this.handle).getContext()['active_ids'];
           var model_name = this.model.get(this.handle).getContext()['active_model'];
           var context = this.model.get(this.handle).getContext()

           var datas = self.model.localData
           var domain ;
           for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(datas)) {
              domain = value.domain;
              break;
            };

            self.do_action({
                type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                res_model: 'imprimer.rapport',
                view_mode: 'form',
                view_type: 'form',
                view_id: 'imprimer_livre_tiers_view',
                views: [[false, 'form']],
                target: 'new',
                context:{"default_domain_record": domain},
               
            });
                 


          },
```